# Add delay in consuming messages in rabbitmq stream

Tags: java, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-stream

i'm using **rabbitmq stream** and i need to add a delay between messages because the stream handles messages very fast.

how can I do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT***
RabbitMQ stream itself sends the messages faster it can but there is a credit mechanism to avoid consumer throttling.
The client sends the credit to get more messages.
At the moment this feature is not exposed we are working on it, so atm it is something you need to do client-side when you produce/consume the messages.

Comment: How can we do that from the client-side when we produce/consume the messages? we're using java and  we can't add the header in rabbitmq stream Environment producer

Comment: @RawanAlKhalawi It's not possible to control the credit mechanism in the stream Java client at the moment. We're open for discussion on how to make this possible. A better channel to discuss this would be the [RabbitMQ Mailing List](https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users) or a [discussion](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-stream-java-client/discussions) in the stream Java client GitHub repository. Thanks.